# Securely run shell command using php from another server

Tags: bash, shell-script, php, remote

I've got Server A where the main website is hosted. I've got a panel there that I'd like to safely run a shell command on Server B every time a new user joins in. I will basically create a new user on Server B. I was thinking of using shell_exec() but not sure how safe that is.

I'm using the following commands:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('IP_ADDRESS', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'pass');
echo ssh2_exec($connection, 'ls');
```

And I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys
```

On the remote server I see the following:

```
Unable to negotiate with IP_ADDRESS port xxx: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing how the two servers are communicating, exactly what this script does, whether any part of the command is provided by the user, whether the script requires root access, etc., but this kind of thing can be done safely if you're careful. Is there some particular thing you're worried about?

Comment: @frabjous I've just added the code I am currently using but it keeps failing. I am basically worried because I kept reading everywhere how unsafe this method is :/

Comment: Your new code doesn't match your original question. What does that have to do with `shell_exec`? Your problem seems to relate specifically to ssh. Can you connect via ssh from the command line?